# WGET recursive download problems

Tags: python

Im attempting to download an entire directory full of PDF's, lets say www.example.com/abc/, so i use the command python wget.py -r -l -0 www.example.com/abc/, and it just returns wget.py: error: no such option: -r

Comment: So take out the `-r`... What do you expect that option to do?

Answer (score 0):

This command works fine:

```
wget -r -l0 www.example.com/abc/
```